Dynamically created div is not showing the values inside a column
I am learning vanilla js. I am trying to create dynamic HTML table from dynamic JSON object.
I have the nested object like below:
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "softwares" : [ {
      "createdBy" : "System",
      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",
      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "id" : 21,
      "softwarename" : "AWS16",
      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",
      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon16.com",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/21"
        },
        "appSoftware" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/21"
        }
      }
    }, ...... ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "first" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=0&size=5"
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=0&size=5"
    },
    "next" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=1&size=5"
    },
    "last" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=4&size=5"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 5,
    "totalElements" : 21,
    "totalPages" : 5,
    "number" : 0
  }
}

Here is what I was able to put up from help from different SO threads.
HTML:
<button id="theButton"> GetData </button>
<div id="tableContainer"></div>

JavaScript:
const button = document.querySelector('#theButton');
button.addEventListener('click', fetchData, false);

function fetchData() {
    button.textContent = 'Loading...';
    button.disabled = true;
    const outputElement = document.getElementById("output");
    setTimeout(() => {
        fetch('/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                //console.log(data);
                // Re-oder the data map
                let myData = data._embedded.softwares.map(function (x) {
                    return {
                        id: x.id,
                        softwarename: x.softwarename,
                        softwareprovider: x.softwareprovider,
                        softwareprovidercontactemail: x.softwareprovidercontactemail,
                        createdBy: x.createdBy,
                        createdDate: x.createdDate,
                        lastModifiedBy: x.lastModifiedBy,
                        lastModifiedDate: x.lastModifiedDate,
                        _links: x._links
                    }
                });
                createTable(myData);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }, 500);

}

function createTable(jsonData) {
    let container = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
    let table = document.createElement("table");
    let cols = Object.keys(jsonData[0]);
    let thead = document.createElement("thead");
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    cols.forEach((item) => {
        let th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerText = item;
        tr.appendChild(th);
    });
    thead.appendChild(tr);
    table.append(tr);

    jsonData.forEach((item) => {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        let vals = Object.values(item);
        vals.forEach((elem) => {
            let td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerText = elem;
            for (let key in elem) {
                if (elem.hasOwnProperty(key) && (typeof elem[key] === "object")) {
                    console.log("key : " + key + ">>  Value:" + elem[key]);
                    let theDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    //theDiv.innerHTML="href : " + elem.self.href + " appSoftware: " + elem.appSoftware.href  ; // Does not work
                    //theDiv.innerHTML=nestedJsonIterator(elem); // Does not work shows object Object
                    //theDiv.textContent=nestedJsonIterator(elem); // Does not work
                    td.textContent = "self : " + elem.self.href + " appSoftware: " + elem.appSoftware.href;
                }
            }

            tr.appendChild(td);

        });
        table.appendChild(tr);
    });
    container.appendChild(table);
    button.remove();
}


function nestedJsonIterator(obj) {
    let text = "";
    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && (typeof obj[key] === "object")) {
            nestedJsonIterator(obj[key])
        } else {
            //console.log("key : " + key + ">>  Value:" + obj[key]);
            text += "key:" + key + " Value:" + obj[key] + "";
        }
    }
    return text;
}

Since the _links is the nested object in Softwares array I am trying to put separate divs inside the links column of the table. For the newly created div(s), I am wondering why theDiv.innerHTML and theDiv.textContent are not working. td.textContent works just fine.  I tried to iterate the nested JSON too  but the table shows blank. What I am missing or doing wrong here?

Are there any errors in your dev console? Where does data come from after your fetch?

No errors whatsoever. Div is either blank or has object Object.

You don't do anything with response.json()

Are you trying to have "a" anchor tag in div?

Yes correct @JatinParmar.

Why do you need to use map()? You're copying all the properties of the array elements, and using the same names. Why not just let myData = data._embedded.softwares?

td.innerText = elem; won't work correctly for the _links element. innerText must be a string, but _links is a nested object.

@Barmar I am re-ordering the columns for the desired presentation on the html.

Conversely, for (let key in elem) won't work correctly for all the elements whose value are strings.

Yeah so how do I show _links values in the column inside individual divs?

Depending on the order of objects properties is a bad idea (I know retaining insertion order is required, it's still confusing). I suggest you use an array containing the desired column order, and iterate over that.

You could use if (typeof elem == 'string') { code for string columns } else { code for nested objects }

So here is the answer for

I am wondering why theDiv.innerHTML and theDiv.textContent are not working.

When you loop over the values of each software entry, the value can be an object or a string. Now you first write in td.innerText with elem - td.innerText = elem;
When elem is an object it will write [object object] (cause of an error) and when it's a string it will write that string (as expected).
After that again you loop through elem object's value to have nested links.
The code to do this is perfectly fine, but inside of loop if you do following:
let theDiv = document.createElement("div");
theDiv.innerHTML="href : " + elem.self.href + " appSoftware: " + elem.appSoftware.href  ; 
theDiv.textContent="href : " + elem.self.href + " appSoftware: " + elem.appSoftware.href  ; 
td.appendChild(theDiv);

Call to td.appendChild(theDiv); will add new child element but will not overwrite [object object] string.
So to fix this we can simply overwrite the td.innerText value
with empty string (that's the reason it works with td.textContent because it overwrites [object object] string).
Here is the corrected code for createTable function:
function createTable(jsonData) {

    let container = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
    let table = document.createElement("table");
    let cols = Object.keys(jsonData[0]);
    let thead = document.createElement("thead");
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    cols.forEach((item) => {
        let th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerText = item;
        tr.appendChild(th);
    });
    thead.appendChild(tr);
    table.append(tr);

    jsonData.forEach((item) => {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        let vals = Object.values(item);
        vals.forEach((elem) => {
            let td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerText = elem;
            for (let key in elem) {
                if (elem.hasOwnProperty(key) && (typeof elem[key] === "object")) {
                    //clear the [object object] string
                    td.innerText = '';
                    let theDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    theDiv.innerHTML="href : " + elem.self.href + " appSoftware: " + elem.appSoftware.href  ; // Does not work
                    td.appendChild(theDiv);
                }
            }

            tr.appendChild(td);

        });
        table.appendChild(tr);
    });
    container.appendChild(table);
    button.remove();
}

I hope this will help you :)

Indeed td.appendChild(theDiv); was the damn missing piece of puzzle. Such small thing completely overlooked. Thanks a lot @Jatin Parmar.
